# codeigniter database info where Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to make page info rendered from database.

I have database:

```
page | title   | description
main | Welcome | This is the main page
```

Controller to get page data and render View

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('url', 'html', 'assets'));
        $this->load->model('pages_model');
    }

    public function index() {

        // This is a page variable
        // in this case it will be "main"
       $page = strtolower(basename(__FILE__, '.php'));


        // Page data
        $data['pg'] =  $this->pages_model->page();

        // Render
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/main', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }

}
```

Then Model where i try to fetch data for specific page

```
    Class Pages_model extends CI_Model {

        function page()
        {
            $query = $this->db->select('*')->where('page', $page)->get('pages');
            return $query->result();
        }

    }
```

But i get error "undefined variable $page in model". How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed to pass "$page" in model. update your code as below:

In controller:

```
  // Page data
        $data['pg'] =  $this->pages_model->page($page);
```

And in model

```
function page($page)
```

Comment: This helps, but how do i pass data to View then?

Comment: found it. in modet i set return $query->row(); and in view i use $pg->column